# Orbiting the earth

Tags: spacecraft, orbital

What is the minimum speed in Km/hour (tangential to earth's surface) required to orbit the earth, at an altitude of 111 Km (well beyond Karman line), where there is no atmospheric drag. Can we achieve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "can we achieve it"?

Comment: At an altitude of 111 km there is atmospheric drag and at 400 km there is still a small drag.

Comment: What is the use of an orbit decaying in much less than one day if not in less than one full orbit?  At 160 km it is about 1 day and at 185 km about 1 week.

Comment: @Organic Marble: AS per my calculation it turned out to be 28,000 km/hour. Which I was not sure if we have achieved it. Anyway, Also, for Uwe: I had read that "Karman" line is considered to be the end of earth's atmosphere. So I presumed there would be no drag at that altitude. I again presume (the way I understood the topic of orbital velocity), that an object can remain in circular orbit at an altitude, if.. the "centrifugal force" generated by its velocity counters the gravitational pull of earth, thereby the object remains in orbit without orbital decay. Am I correct?

Answer (score 4):

You can pretty easily figure out this kind of thing from a calculator like [this one](https://rechneronline.de/g-acceleration/orbital-speed.php). For your specific answer, using 1 Earth mass, a distance of 6482 km (111 km above Earth), we determine the velocity to be 7.843 km/s. And we have achieved much higher velocities in the past, so we absolutely can achieve that.

Lastly, there is actually drag at that altitude. It isn't much, but a spacecraft in such a low orbit will tend to reenter within a few days, if not shorter. A much higher orbit is desired.

Comment: I thought that if an object travels at a velocity, which is high enough that the centrifugal force experienced by the object will be exactly equal to the gravitational force of earth, the object can remain in orbit without any decay. (Except for the decay caused by difference in earth's diameter at poles and at equator, which might call for an elliptical orbit. Am I wrong in thinking so?

Comment: @Niranjan - While it is true that if the velocity is high enough centrifugal force balances gravitational force, atmospheric drag will slow satellites down until they are less than that velocity.  Orbits "decay" until the perigee brings them into denser atmoshphere where the satellite will be destroyed by frictional heating.  Satellites experience some atmospheric drag at altitudes in 100s of km.  The Karman line doesn't mean the atmosphere vanishes; it's more a guideline of where aerodynamic lift becomes negligible.

Comment: @antlersoft - Oh. So if I have understood this correctly, partial atmosphere - may be very rare gases etc, does exist beyond Karman line (100 km), which provides the drag & thus reduces the speed, which eventually does not experience enough centrifugal force to prevent its decay. Right? So at what altitude can one say the drag would be ZERO? If there is any such altitude? (I thought stage one of any rocket should be designed to take the vehicle only upto that point. after that, we would have to spend minimum fuel, even to reach moon, although very very slow.) Very useful answer. Thanks.